# How to get Pandas column multiindex names as a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following CSV data:

```
id,gene,celltype,stem,stem,stem,bcell,bcell,tcell
id,gene,organs,bm,bm,fl,pt,pt,bm
134,foo,about_foo,20,10,11,23,22,79
222,bar,about_bar,17,13,55,12,13,88
```

And I can successfully summarize them this way:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("http://dpaste.com/1X74TNP.txt",header=None,index_col=[1,2]).iloc[:, 1:]

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(df.ix[:2].values)
df = df.ix[2:].astype(int)
df.index.names = ['cell', 'organ']
df = df.reset_index('organ', drop=True)

result = df.groupby(level=[0, 1], axis=1).mean()
result = result.stack().replace(np.nan, 0).unstack()
result = result.swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```

Which looks like:

```
In [341]: result
Out[341]:
        bm               fl               pt
     bcell stem tcell bcell stem tcell bcell stem tcell
cell
foo      0   15    79     0   11     0  22.5    0     0
bar      0   15    88     0   55     0  12.5    0     0
```

My question is, from `result` how can I get the column index of the first level as list:

```
['bm','fl','pt']
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`result.columns` returns a `pandas.core.index.MultiIndex` which has a levels attribute.

```
list(result.columns.levels[0])
```

returns

```
['bm', 'fl', 'pt']
```

Comment: Note: These will not be in the original order

Answer (score 8):

Additionally you could use columnns.get_level_values(level)

```
 >>> result.columns.get_level_values(0).unique()
    array(['bm', 'fl', 'pt'], dtype=object)
 >>> list(result.columns.get_level_values(0))
    ['bm', 'bm', 'bm', 'fl', 'fl', 'fl', 'pt', 'pt', 'pt']
```