# How to get Pandas column multiindex FULL name as a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame `df` as:

```
    A          B
    V1   V2    V1   V3    V4
ID 
 1  10   20    30   40    50
 2  60   70    80   90    100
```

How do I get the list:

```
>> ["A.V1", "A.V2", "B.V1", "B.V3", "B.V4"]
```

This [Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34082137/how-to-get-pandas-column-multiindex-names-as-a-list) asks a similar question. However, the asker wants only the 'short' name. If applied to my question, it would result in:

```
>> ["A", "B"]
```

I tried writing my own implementation:

```
def get_multiindex_full_names(multiindex):
    if (type(multiindex) != pd.core.index.MultiIndex):
        print("ArgError: Input type is not a MultiIndex!")
        return 

    _lvs = multiindex.levels
    _n = len(_lvs)

    assert(_n > 0)

    _l = _lvs[0]

    def str_cross_product(la, lb):
        """ Returns String Cross product between list a and list b

        @return list of strings
        """
        return [".".join([a, b]) for a in la for b in lb]


    for i in range (1, _n):
        _l = str_cross_product(_l, _lvs[i])

    return _l
```

However, this doesn't work because it would result in:

```
get_multiindex_full_names(df.columns)
>> ["A.V1", "A.V2", "A.V3", "A.V4", "B.V1", "B.V2", "B.V3", "B.V4"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
df.columns.map('.'.join)
```

#### Test Code:

```
df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(u"""
     ID A    A     B    B     B
     ID V1   V2    V1   V3    V4
     1  10   20    30   40    50
     2  60   70    80   90    100"""),
                 header=[1, 2], index_col=0)
print(df)
print(list(df.columns.map('.'.join)))
```

#### Results:

```
ID   A       B         
ID  V1  V2  V1  V3   V4
1   10  20  30  40   50
2   60  70  80  90  100

['A.V1', 'A.V2', 'B.V1', 'B.V3', 'B.V4']
```